# bigquery import job fails with "System error"

Tags: google-bigquery

One of my import jobs is failing continuously with the error "Errors encountered during job execution. System error"

Job id is bqjob_r2257fe91a590a308_0000014e3e922faf_1

I can get the following information from the system

```
root@6bd6c7262e96:/opt/batch/jobs# bq show -j bqjob_r2257fe91a590a308_0000014e3e922faf_1
Job infra-bedrock-861:bqjob_r2257fe91a590a308_0000014e3e922faf_1

Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration   Bytes Processed
---------- --------- ----------------- ---------- -----------------
load       FAILURE   29 Jun 09:07:42   0:00:02

Errors encountered during job execution. System error. The error has been logged and we will investigate.
```

Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Is it something new? did it always do that? did something change? what's different between this and your succesful imports?

Comment: This is a very odd failure. If you don't mind, can you grant me read access to the GCS files referenced in that load job? msheldon@google.com. Feel free to email me and we can continue the investigation. Thank you.

Comment: Update: this looks like poor error mapping on our part, and the problem should have been reported as a transient "backendError". Just to confirm: if you retry the load operation does it work? Thank you!

Comment: @Patrice I have not changed the import. I'm uploading logfiles on an hourly basis, and this exact hour fails, so it is probably some odd data in the files

Comment: @MichaelSheldon will mail you